# building where clause based on google visualization category picker control

Tags: javascript, for-loop, controls, google-visualization

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721749/get-the-type-of-category-filter-control), we can execute a function based on Google visualization category picker control. Now I am trying to build same type of where clause based on three controls as given below.

```
var whereClause1;
var control1, control2, control3;
function drawVisualization() {
    // etc.
    control1 = // etc...

    control2 = // etc...

    control3 = // etc...

    // Register to hear state changes.
    google.visualization.events.addListener(control1, 'statechange', foo1);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(control2, 'statechange', foo2);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(control3, 'statechange', foo3);

  // etc.
}
function foo1() {
    var whereClauses = [];  
    if (control1.getState().selectedValues == '') {
        whereClauses.push("Something")
    }
    else if (control1) {
        whereClauses.push("Something1 = '" +control1.getState().selectedValues+ "'")
    }
    whereClause1 = whereClauses; 

    dothis();
}

function foo2() {
    var whereClauses = [];  
    if (control2.getState().selectedValues == '') {
        whereClauses.push("Something1 = '" +control1.getState().selectedValues+ "'")
    }
    else if (control2) {
        whereClauses.push("Something2 = '" +control2.getState().selectedValues+ "'")
    }
    whereClause1 = whereClauses; 

    dothis();
}

function foo3() {
    var whereClauses = [];  
    if (control3.getState().selectedValues == '') {
        whereClauses.push("Something2 = '" +control2.getState().selectedValues+ "'")
    }
    else if (control3) {
        whereClauses.push("Something3 = '" +control3.getState().selectedValues+ "'")
    }
    whereClause1 = whereClauses; 

    dothis();
}

function dothis() {
    whereClause += " AND " + whereClause1;
}
```

How can I merge the three functions in to one single function `foo` using some loop?

**EDIT :** Find my sample [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/87sB9/).

In the sample, when i choose 'A' in column 1, the where clause should take value `column0 = 'Home' AND column1 = 'A'` and when I choose 'bar' in column 2, the where clause should take value `column0 = 'Home' AND column1 = 'A' AND column2 = 'bar'` and if I choose 'bar' and '200' in column2 and column3 respectively, the where clause should take value `column0 = 'Home' AND column2 = 'bar' AND column3 = '200'` and so on.

Also it take reverse order too. That is, when I choose 'Choose a value' in column 2, the where clause should take value that is set in column 1 only. I am tried with the following:

```
function foo() {
    var whereClauses = [];  
    if (control1.getState().selectedValues == '')    { whereClauses.push("") }
    if (control1)    { whereClauses.push("Column1 = '" +control1.getState().selectedValues+ "'") }
    if (control2.getState().selectedValues == '')    { whereClauses.push("Column1 = '" +control1.getState().selectedValues+ "'") }
    if (control2)    { whereClauses.push("Column2 = '" +control2.getState().selectedValues+ "'") }
    if (control3.getState().selectedValues == '')    { whereClauses.push("Column2 = '" +control2.getState().selectedValues+ "'") }
    if (control3)    { whereClauses.push("Column3 = '" +control3.getState().selectedValues+ "'") }
    whereClause1 = whereClauses.join(" AND ");

    dothis();
  }
```

But no use.

Comment: There are different ways you can merge them, and how you do so depends on what you want to happen.  I think that if you write out your logical process for what you want to happen when any control changes state, the function will become apparent.

Comment: see the edit for details. Added a [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87sB9/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, this function should do what you want:

```
function getWhereClause () {
    var selectedValues1 = control1.getState().selectedValues;
    var selectedValues2 = control2.getState().selectedValues;
    var selectedValues3 = control3.getState().selectedValues;
    var whereClauses = ["column0 = 'Home'"];

    if (selectedValues1.length) {
        whereClauses.push("Column1 = '" + selectedValues1[0] + "'");
    }
    if (selectedValues2.length) {
        whereClauses.push("Column2 = '" + selectedValues2[0] + "'");
    }
    if (selectedValues3.length) {
        whereClauses.push("Column3 = '" + selectedValues3[0] + "'");
    }
    var whereClause = whereClauses.join(' AND ');
    // do something with whereClause
    alert(whereClause);
}
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/zrjnh/